# Check if user is looking at screen from code

Tags: android, ios, face-recognition, iphone-x

In newer Android devices there's the possibility to unlock the phone with your face. It will also be possible with the Iphone X.

Is there a way of using these sensors/camera to check if the user is looking at the screen?

**Edit:** 
I found that there's also a Vision Framework from Google: [Vision Framework](https://developers.google.com/vision/)

Comment: The docs you link for the Google vision framework don't mention gaze tracking / attention detection as a feature of that technology.

Comment: [This link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces) has an Apple official demo project showing the usage of position and orientation of eyes starting on iOS 12. You could build your own logic to add a virtual plane that mimics size and position/orientation of the device and see if the eye ray intersects that plane (your device), a fairly advanced usage/knowledge of AR is needed for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

The built-in Face ID feature on iPhone X can unlock the device and authorize other built-in features (Apple Pay, iTunes/App Store payment, etc). You can also use it as a method of authorization in your app — the same [LocalAuthentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication) framework calls that you use to support Touch ID on other devices automatically use Face ID instead on iPhone X.

Face ID, by default, requires the user to be looking at the screen. Thus, if your use case for attention detection has to do with authorization or unlocking, you can use LocalAuthentication to do it. (However, the user can disable attention detection in Accessibility settings, reducing the security but increasing the usability of Face ID. Third-party apps can't control or even read this setting.)

---

If you're talking about more directly doing attention detection or gaze tracking... Apple doesn't provide any API that exposes the inner workings of Face ID, or at least the gaze tracking part. Here's what they do have:

- ARKit offers [`ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacetrackingconfiguration) (see also [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences)), which provides a detailed 3D model of the face in real time (supposedly using some of the same Neural Engine stuff as Face ID for detail and performance).

  But as far as ARKit is concerned, eyes are just two holes in the face — there's no gaze tracking.
- Apple's [Vision framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) offers face detection and face landmark recognition (that is, it locates eyes, nose, mouth, etc). Vision does identify the eye outline and the pupil, which you could theoretically use as a basis for gaze tracking.

  However, since Vision offers such data only in 2D and doesn't get a 3D pose for the face, you're still left with a hefty computer vision problem if you want to build gaze tracking yourself. Vision processes 2D images, which means that it doesn't require iPhone X (but also means that it doesn't benefit from the TrueDepth camera on iPhone X either).
- [AVCapture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture) offers access to the TrueDepth camera, so you can get the same color + depth imagery that Face ID and ARKit use to do their magic. (You just don't get said magic for yourself.)

None of this is to say that gaze tracking isn't possible on iOS in general or iPhone X specifically — all the building blocks are there, so given enough R&D effort you can implement it yourself. But Apple doesn't provide any developer access to the built-in gaze tracking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in iOS 11 developer can use this feature in their third party application too through the iOS latest [Vision Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision)

Comment: Very nice, I will definitely check out this framework.

Answer (score 0):

Whole idea behind this feature is using front camera with facial recognition.
But you have to optimise it for when to capture images for processing

Tips

1. On application become active or become in foreground.
2. Also when user interact with any UI control or widget like (buttons,
   table , touch events etc ).
3. Make sure stop or pause processing when
   application not active.
4. Also you can use Gyroscope and other sensors to find device physical state.

Comment: Yes, optimisation is needed for sure. Do you know anything about the computing power, which is needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to bulk up your app with a ML model, Google's [media pipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) is another option. You can even track the user's iris in this way:
https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/iris

Obviously this is a overkill for simple eye detection, but you should be able to do much more with these models and framework.